# Spring Security with JaasAuthenticationProvider using Krb5LoginModule

Tags: spring, spring-security, kerberos, jaas, spring-java-config

I try to develop a web application which uses Kerberos for authentication. I started by setting up a secure web application with a `JaasAuthenticationProvider` and a configuration `login.conf`

```
KerberosContext
{
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
    required
    useTicketCache=true
    doNotPrompt=false;
};
```

My SecurityConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JaasAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

The web application now displays a form login (which is correct, if I am not authenticated via SPNEGO) and I can login with my credentials of my active directory.

But how can I skip this, when I do already have a TGT? Currently I must submit the login form with any content and will be authenticated with my identity.
Sample output of my TestController:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.jaas.JaasAuthenticationToken@e72aef67:
Principal: ; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: 
RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: <...>; Granted 
Authorities: Jaas Authority [ROLE_USER,username@MYREALM]
```